# Encoding issue on SQL script fails deployment through PowerShell script

Tags: sql-server, powershell, utf-8, encode, collation

I am trying to deploy a database (on `SQL Server`) using a script (data insert with `MERGE INTO` statement) which has column name in a table as **Certificate 12 nÂ°**. Deployment uses `PowerShell` scripts. Database properties has `Finnish_Swedish_CI_AS` for `Collation`.

**Problem:** Manual insert works using the column name. But while executing the script through the `PowerShell` script, it gives the following error

> Invalid column name 'Certificate 12 n�'°'.

**nÂ°** is getting translated as **n�'°**

**Question:** How can the columan name be kept as it is (**Certificate 12 nÂ°**) and still be able to execute the `SQL` script using `PowerShell` script? Or anyother better way to handle unsual characters?

`SQL` code:

```
MERGE INTO TableABCD target
USING (
SELECT  'Romania' AS COUNTRY, 'Head office ' AS [STORE NAME] ,'1234' AS [STORE ID], 'dsfsdf' AS Address, NULL AS [Certificate 11 nÂ°] , NULL AS [Certificate 121 nÂ°], NULL AS [Certificate _issue date] , 2015 AS YEAR, 6 AS MONTH, '201506' AS YM UNION
SELECT  'Spain' AS COUNTRY, 'Head office' AS [STORE NAME] ,'1122' AS [STORE ID], 'sdfsdf' AS Address, NULL AS [Certificate 11 nÂ°] , NULL AS [Certificate 121 nÂ°], NULL AS [Certificate _issue date] , 2015 AS YEAR, 6 AS MONTH, '201506' AS YM UNION
SELECT  'UK' AS COUNTRY, 'Head office' AS [STORE NAME] ,'1243' AS [STORE ID], 'sdfdf ' AS Address, NULL AS [Certificate 11 nÂ°] , NULL AS [Certificate 121 nÂ°], NULL AS [Certificate _issue date] , 2015 AS YEAR, 6 AS MONTH, '201506' AS YM UNION
SELECT  'Italy' AS COUNTRY, 'Head office' AS [STORE NAME] ,'1514' AS [STORE ID], 'dsfdfs' AS Address, NULL AS [Certificate 11 nÂ°] , NULL AS [Certificate 121 nÂ°], NULL AS [Certificate _issue date] , 2015 AS YEAR, 6 AS MONTH, '201506' AS YM
) source ON (target.COUNTRY = source.COUNTRY and target.[STORE ID] = source.[STORE ID] and target.ym = source.ym)
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
  INSERT (COUNTRY, [STORE NAME], [STORE ID], Address, [Certificate 11 nÂ°], [Certificate 121 nÂ°], [Certificate _issue date], YEAR, MONTH, ym)
VALUES (COUNTRY, [STORE NAME], [STORE ID], Address, [Certificate 11 nÂ°], [Certificate 121 nÂ°], [Certificate _issue date], YEAR, MONTH, ym)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
UPDATE SET
    target.COUNTRY = source.COUNTRY,
    target.[STORE NAME] = source.[STORE NAME],
    target.[STORE ID] = source.[STORE ID],
    target.Address = source.Address ,
    target.[Certificate 11 nÂ°] = source.[Certificate 11 nÂ°] ,
    target.[Certificate 121 nÂ°] = source.[Certificate 121 nÂ°] ,
    target.[Certificate _issue date] = source.[Certificate _issue date] ,
    target.YEAR = source.YEAR,
    target.MONTH = source.MONTH,
    target.YM = source.YM
```

;

Comment: Looks like Ascii/Unicode translation error. What encoding the Powershell script file is using?

Comment: Powershell, being .Net, should be handling everything with UTF-8.  So should the providers.  I created a test table and queried it from Powershell  with no problems (`Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance mysrv -Database mydb -Query 'select [Certificate 12 nÂ°] from test'`).  Post your code.

Comment: Check your spelling.  The SQL code you posted only refers to a field named `[Certificate 121 nÂ°]` but your error message refers to `[Certificate 12 nÂ°]`.  Maybe you dropped a character somewhere?

Comment: that is not the issue. This is just a sample code. That is a column name and I have `[Certificate 121 nÂ°]`, `[Certificate 12 nÂ°]` and many more.